# Solr NonRepeatableRequestException in save action

Tags: solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I have configured Spring data solr 1.5.4 to use Apache Solr 5.2.1 and this is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
    return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory());
}

@Bean
public SolrServerFactory solrServerFactory() {
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
return new HttpSolrServerFactory(solrServer(), "", credentials, "BASIC");
}

@Bean
public SolrServer solrServer() {
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_ALLOW_COMPRESSION, true);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_USER, username);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_PASS, password);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 12345);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 22345);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST, 32345);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_SO_TIMEOUT, 42345);
    params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_USE_RETRY, false);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientUtil.createClient(params);
    HttpSolrServer httpSolrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/solr/", httpClient);
    return httpSolrServer;
}
```

but when I want to save the document, this exception occurs:

```
14:28:45,863 Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.

14:28:45,863    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:660)

14:28:45,863    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)

14:28:45,863    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Until this is fixed, implement `PreemptiveAuthInterceptor` and `addRequestInterceptor` before `createClient`

Sample is available at [PreemptiveAuthInterceptor.java](https://github.com/codelibs/solrlib/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codelibs/solr/lib/server/interceptor/PreemptiveAuthInterceptor.java)

e.g.

```java
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.add(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_USER, uname);
    params.add(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_PASS, pwd);
    params.add(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_PASS, pwd);
    HttpClientUtil.addRequestInterceptor(new PreemptiveAuthInterceptor());      
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientUtil.createClient(params);
```

Comment: Yes! It is unbelievable that after so many years the problem has not been solved on behalf of SOLR. I just had to modify the PreemptiveAuthInterceptor so it does not duplicates the Authorization header